# input tags should fit in same row instead of second row css issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a0LvLj7x/92/)

I have used [bootstrap tags](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) for my current system. But when the input tags are added more than 6 or 7 then it keeps adding in the second row. I want to fit it to first row like this image doesn't want to make it second row. Please help me with css.
[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.tags').tagsinput({
     allowDuplicates: true
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/assets/app.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
    <input type="text" value="" class="tags" />
    <div class="items"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you tag input field have a fixed width if elements exceed that width they are shifted down

Comment: yes I understood that. Can you give a solution for this. I dont want to extend the width or taking to second line. I want it should fit to first line itself. Example in an input field u can enter maximum number of character but it dont get extend or go to second line. It will keep adding to right side. I want something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this to your css

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

see working example: http://jsfiddle.net/a0LvLj7x/93/

Comment: Thank you its a better solution :)

Comment: If my answer helped you, you could also accept my answer so that it could help me and others as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `white-space: nowrap` for this. check updated snippet below..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tags').tagsinput({
    allowDuplicates: true
  });
});
```

```css
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/assets/app.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
    <input type="text" value="" class="tags" />
    <div class="items"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If i use `white-space: nowrap` the input field width is extending. I don't want to extend. I want to fit to given width. If the tags increase also it should fit to given width. example you can give maximum number of characters in an input but it dont go out of the input field. something like that i want

Comment: if you need auto scroll then you can use nicescroll or slim scroll plugins

Answer (score 0):

add overflow scroll like this to this class

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: none;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tags').tagsinput({
    allowDuplicates: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/assets/app.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
    <input type="text" value="" class="tags" />
    <div class="items"></div>
</div>
```